# Glut Documentation on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opengl, documentation, glut

Is it possible to add Glut and openGL documentation to Visual Studio 2010? How is it done?
Intellisense indeed works, but I wondered if it was possible to add also the documentation when browsing the functions from the intellisense menu.